# Javascript Download to excel sheet

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

There is an HTML table as

```
<table>
       <tr><th>NAME</th></tr>
       <tr><td>SAL</td></tr>
       <tr><td>TOM</td></tr>
       <tr><td>SAM</td></tr>
       <tr><td>Jenny</td></tr>
</table>
```

Download to excel sheet

On click hyperlink how to save the table to excel sheet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function makeSheet() {
var x = theTable.rows

var xls = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application")
xls.visible = true
xls.Workbooks.Add
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++){
  var y = x[i].cells
for (j = 0; j < y.length; j++){
     xls.Cells( i+1, j+1).Value = y[j].innerText
   }
  }
}
```

Comment: theTable is the id of the table is it??

Comment: document.getElementById("theTable")

Comment: Interesting, but it seems to works only with IE. I am looking for similar solutions for Firefox.

Comment: @ruffp ActiveX runs only in IE.

Comment: Yes you are right, finally we choose another way by building the excel xml by using an xslt transformation instead using javascript (web publication was not a must have)

Answer (score 3):

You might want to try using the XLSX.js lib http://blog.innovatejs.com/?tag=xlsx-js

There is an example there on how to export to excel which gives examples.

Note this exports to the XLSX format not XLS. But this should not be a problem for most use. The source is on GitHub: https://github.com/stephen-hardy/xlsx.js

Answer (score 2):

You may want to take a look at [table2CSV](http://www.kunalbabre.com/projects/table2CSV.php), since Excel can open csv files with no problem (and as a bonus other software can do it too, like OpenOffice). If you need it to be cross-browser, there's no way of generating a downloadable file, for that you need a server side script like the one in the example in the page I linked.

Answer (score 1):

I have developed a product called [scriptscraper](http://www.scriptscraper.com) which is designed to solve that problem.

Get the trial installed because the demonstration projects download data from yahoo finance and store the data in Excel.  For that simple html table it would be no problem to do what you need.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong ... runs as a stand-alone Windows process, as opposed to something that could be referenced from any old HTML page and used to open up Excel on the local system? Also, it looks like it's 35mb, yikes.